# OrderedDict in Django tests

Tags: python, django

I have such Django tests

```
queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
response = self.client.get("some_url")
serializer = SomeSerializer(
    instance=list(queryset[:10]), many=True
)
self.assertEqual(
    serializer.data,
    response.json()["results"],
)
```

And got such error

```
E   AssertionError: [OrderedDict([('uuid', 'e58fecc0-d559-41af[23258 chars]))])] != [{'uuid': 'e58fecc0-d559-41af-993b-9519309[17732 chars]0.0}]
```

How can be OrderedDict be removed or transformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was even simpler. Instead of `response.json()` `response.data` should be used, because `response.data` returns same as serializer.data

The final result will be

```
queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
response = self.client.get("some_url")
serializer = SomeSerializer(
    instance=list(queryset[:10]), many=True
)
self.assertEqual(
    serializer.data,
    response.data["results"],
)
```

And test passes.

Comment: Question was - How can be OrderedDict be removed or transformed?

Comment: @MaximDanilov - that's why I said about elegance

Answer (score 2):

Obviously:

```
self.assertEqual(dict(serializer.data), response.json()["results"], msg="Please dont forget an error message")
```

But it is not so obviously:

`AssretEqual` falls if the compared dictionaries are with different order. And in your case - you should check the value of `uuid`, not the dictionaries themselves.

```
self.assertEqual(serializer.data['uuid'], response.json()["results"]['uuid'], msg="Please dont forget an error message")
```

Thanks to **@Headmaster** comment:
You should check, if you have really dictionary or list of dictionaries. It depends on your `serializer.__class__`.

Comment: serializer.data is a list

Comment: @Headmaster i am not agree. Drf has class Serializer and class class ListSerializer.  (rest_framework/serializers.py) serializer.to_representation method returns ordered dict. ListSerializer.to_representation returns list.

Comment: you can check https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer

Comment: @Headmaster see my answer, i improve it

Comment: I found more elegant answer. Feel free to use that in future. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73595063/5594008